# Does Sylow's theorem assert the existence of subgroups of order $p^j$ for all $j=1,\dots,k$ ?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Sylow's theorem says that there exists a subgroup of order $p^k$, where $p^k$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing the order of the group.

But for example if   the group order is $24$, then we can write $24$ as $2^3 \cdot 3$. So there exists a subgroup of order $2^3 = 8$, but does Sylow's theorem also say that there exists subgroups of orders $2$ and $4$ as well (from $2^1$ and $2^2$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Sylow's first theorem can be widened to the following:

> *Claim* Let $G$ be a finite group of order $p^nm$, $(m,p)=1$. Then for each $k=1,\ldots,n$ there exists a group of order $p^k$, and every group of order $p^k$ is normal in a group of order $p^{k+1}$.

This in particular gives that every finite $p$-group is solvable right away. In fact, finite $p$-groups are supersolvable.

Comment: Oh, but what about $2^1 \cdot 12$? These are not coprime, so does that mean the assurance of a subgroup of order $2$ (in my initial example) is not guaranteed?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ No, that's not what I said. That $(m,p)=1$ just means $n$ is as high as we can get. =)

Comment: Sorry, I've never seen the notation $(m, p)$ before. What does it mean? I thought it meant common factors of $m$ and $p$.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ It means $\gcd(m,p)$.

Comment: But for $2^1 \cdot 12$, gcd($12, 2) = 2$, not $1$ like your definition says.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ I know that. But that doesn't matter. The theorem says, write $|G|=p^n m$ where $n$ is the highest number such that $p^n\mid |G|$, then blah blah blah. For $24$, write $2^33$. Then the theorem says we have subgroups of order $2,4,8$.

Comment: I just realized that you are pinging user "ಠ_ಠ". At first I thought you were prefacing each comment with a disapproval face, which I thought was a little odd :/